# Using regex to filter a URL list

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use regex to filter a list of site that doesn't include a specific word.

For example from the list below, i want to filter all sites with the word test and empty strings so the final output that I'll get is http://example.com. I tried to use `^((?!test).)*` but that doesn't filter empty strings. Maybe there is a better way to filter them? Thanks.

```
http://test1.com
http://test2.com
*empty string*
http://example.com
```

Comment: You can use: `^(?!.*test).+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookahead and `.+` in your regex as this:

```
^(?!.*test).+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1dAnaA/1)